# Find a pair of even number in array and insert their average between them

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I have started learning C few days ago and I have difficulty with this simple task.

What I need to do, is:

> In dynamic array (all the numbers should be entered by the user) find a pair of even numbers and their average ( (arr[i] +
>   arr[i+1])/2) ) should be added between that pair of even numbers

I wrote this piece of code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int *fillArray(int *arraySize);
int findPairs(int *array, int arraySize);
int newArray(int *array, int arraySize, int avg, int avgPos);
void printArray(int *array, int arraySize);
int main() {
   int *array;
   int arraySize;

   // Creating the array
   array = fillArray(&arraySize);

   // Printing the array, which was entered
   printf("You just have entered this: \n");
   printArray(array, arraySize);

   // Finding a pair of even numbers
   findPairs(array, arraySize);

   // Printing the new array
   printf("The new array looks like this now! \n");
   printArray(array, arraySize);

   free(array);

   _getch();
}

// Creating dynamicly allocated array
int *createArray(int arraySize) {
   int *array;

   array = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) * arraySize);
   if (array == NULL) {
       printf("No memmory avaible/n");
       exit(8);
   }

   return array;
}

// Function for filling the array with elements
int *fillArray(int *arraySize) {
    int *array = NULL;

    // Array size
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    while (*arraySize < 2) {
        scanf_s("%d", *&arraySize);
        if (*arraySize < 2) {
            printf("Array size should be bigger than 2! \n");
            scanf_s("%d", *&arraySize);
        }
    }

    // Calling function for creating array
    array = createArray(*arraySize);

    // Filling the array with numbers
    printf("Enter %d numbers: \n", *arraySize);
    for (int i = 0; i < *arraySize; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    return array;
}

// Function for finding pairs of even numbers
int findPairs(int *array, int arraySize) {
    int avg = 0, avgPos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[i + 1] % 2 == 0) {
            avg = (array[i] + array[i + 1]) / 2;
            avgPos = i + 1;

            //Resizing the array size +1 position
            *array = newArray(array, arraySize, avg, avgPos);

            i++;
        }
    }
    return *array;
}

// Function transfering into new array
int newArray(int *array, int arraySize, int avg, int avgPos) {
    int *newArr = NULL;

    arraySize++;
    newArr = createArray(arraySize);

    // Copy all the elements from 0 to the first position of first pair even numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < avgPos; i++) {
        newArr[i] = array[i];
    }

    // Add the average number between the even numbers
    newArr[avgPos] = avg;

    // Copy rest of the elements
    for (int i = avgPos + 1; i < arraySize; i++) {
        newArr[i] = array[i - 1];
    }

    free(array);

    return *newArr;
}

// Function for printing the array
void printArray(int *array, int arraySize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]); printf("\n");
    }
}
```

It starts in console without any problems, but after you fill the array with numbers, you will get this error:

Error after filling the array:

[image: Error after filling the array]

Errors in error list:

[image: Errors in error list]

Where have I made the mistake?

Comment: Don't post images of text! See [ask].

Comment: Have you consdired creating a list?

Comment: I can't post images, I need 10 points for that. Sorry about that!
@Mariei What kind of a list?

Comment: at `fillArray` 1) `while (*arraySize < 2) {` `*arraySize` is uninitialized 2) `scanf_s("%d", *&arraySize);` --> `scanf_s("%d", arraySize);`

Comment: ^ Fix the first problem by using a `do...while` loop.

Comment: Maybe `for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)` → `for (int i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++)` in `findPairs` function.

Comment: `return *newArr;` --> `return newArr;` also `int *newArray(` and `array = newArray(`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Isn't `scanf_s("%d", *&arraySize);` and `scanf_s("%d", arraySize);` the same?

Comment: @CoolGuy yes, it's  same. but `*&` is needless.

Comment: Also change to `int *findPairs(` , `return array;` and `array=findPairs(`

Comment: Also `arraySize++;` Resizing does not propagate to caller-side.

Comment: I've tried all of the above suggestions, but the problem still remains. I've noticed, that if there is no pair of even numbers - I will not get a crash.
So the problem is in newArray function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (Those subjected to modifications that have already been pointed out)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int *fillArray(int *arraySize);
int *findPairs(int *array, int *arraySize);
int *newArray(int *array, int arraySize, int avg, int avgPos);
void printArray(int *array, int arraySize);
int main() {
   int *array;
   int arraySize = 0;

   // Creating the array
   array = fillArray(&arraySize);

   // Printing the array, which was entered
   printf("You just have entered this: \n");
   printArray(array, arraySize);

   // Finding a pair of even numbers
   array=findPairs(array, &arraySize);

   // Printing the new array
   printf("The new array looks like this now! \n");
   printArray(array, arraySize);

   free(array);

   _getch();
}

// Creating dynamicly allocated array
int *createArray(int arraySize) {
   int *array;

   array = (int*) malloc ( sizeof(int) * arraySize);
   if (array == NULL) {
       printf("No memmory avaible/n");
       exit(8);
   }

   return array;
}

// Function for filling the array with elements
int *fillArray(int *arraySize) {
    int *array = NULL;

    // Array size
    printf("Enter array size: ");
    while (*arraySize < 2) {
        scanf_s("%d", arraySize);
        if (*arraySize < 2) {
            printf("Array size should be bigger than 2! \n");
            scanf_s("%d", arraySize);
        }
    }

    // Calling function for creating array
    array = createArray(*arraySize);

    // Filling the array with numbers
    printf("Enter %d numbers: \n", *arraySize);
    for (int i = 0; i < *arraySize; i++) {
        scanf_s("%d", &array[i]);
    }

    return array;
}

// Function for finding pairs of even numbers
int *findPairs(int *array, int *arraySize) {
    int avg = 0, avgPos = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < *arraySize -1; i++) {
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0 && array[i + 1] % 2 == 0) {
            avg = (array[i] + array[i + 1]) / 2;
            avgPos = i + 1;

            //Resizing the array size +1 position
            array = newArray(array, *arraySize, avg, avgPos);
            ++*arraySize;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

// Function transfering into new array
int *newArray(int *array, int arraySize, int avg, int avgPos) {
    int *newArr = NULL;

    arraySize++;
    newArr = createArray(arraySize);

    // Copy all the elements from 0 to the first position of first pair even numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < avgPos; i++) {
        newArr[i] = array[i];
    }

    // Add the average number between the even numbers
    newArr[avgPos] = avg;

    // Copy rest of the elements
    for (int i = avgPos + 1; i < arraySize; i++) {
        newArr[i] = array[i - 1];
    }

    free(array);

    return newArr;
}

// Function for printing the array
void printArray(int *array, int arraySize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]); printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've missed something out, like ++*arraySize. Thank you!